# broadleaf Java Mail gmail smtp not working in Cent OS

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

I am just sending the email to users via gmail account. Everything works fine in my development environment (windows 7), but when i move to production cent OS, then its throwing the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
at com.product.mailservice.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:90)
```

Comment: Are you trying to access gmail from a completely different region from which you have never accessed the mail id? If yes, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311823/java-mail-fails-to-authenticate-smtp-setting-in-openshift-server

Answer (score 0):

Check your production runtime properties, if you have set the proper values/credentials. By default broadleaf uses development.properties as runtime environment. Verify that you start your application server with the correct runtime environment -Druntime.environment=production.

Comment: We are able to confirm that proper credentials are saved in the properties file as well as those credentials are working 
Further telnet to smtp.gmail.com 465 is also working from that Cent OS